# How can we use any async function or thread in cakephp 2

Tags: multithreading, cakephp

- How can we use any async function or thread in cakephp 2.
- I have tried [dereuromark blog](https://www.dereuromark.de/2013/12/22/queue-deferred-execution-in-cakephp/) and [cakeresque](http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/install) link for solution. But got error on Resque class not found though everything installed correctly.
- Is there any other way which I can try.
- I want to run generating pdf in thread job and do not affect on current process.
- I goth this issue too [Github:Unable to explicitly require a dev version](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1918)

Comment: What was your issue? Using e.g. [Queue](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue) to generate PDFs should work just fine.

Comment: @mark I have upgrade PHP version and its working fine. Now it's working for me.

Comment: You should upgrade to Cake3 though :) Lots of more and better functionality, also in plugin eco system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PHP 7 or above to implement Threading and async functionality